# CSS with fading image in and out

Tags: css, switch-statement, toggle

I've got a ux switch that toggles a pictures effect on and off.

http://plnkr.co/edit/JcPXpP0jE5GysBbZbrkp

I want the picture to fade from one to the other over 1 second, but I can't seem to get the fade working in CSS. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
.off 
{ 
    opacity: 1; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in; 
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in; 
    position:relative; 
    z-index:2; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see there is no animation because you are swapping img `src` attribute. This swap is impossible to animate. What I suggest is that you load both images, place one behind the other and animate opacity of the one in front. Here is my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7uakbxwZETNnBiOAOfys?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the jQuery fade instead: make a .js file, link it to your .html file and try this:

```
    $(document).ready(
        $('#yourSwitch').click(
           $('#yourImage').fadeOut();
        );
    );
```

And the opposite when you try to make it fade in:

```
   $(document).ready(
        $('#yourSwitch').click(
           $('#yourImage').fadeOut();
        );
    );
```

Comment: I think with my plnkr code I am fading the same element so fadeIn() and fadeOut() would just toggle the opacity. What I am really trying to do is have the black and white image there in the off position, and the colored in the on position. Making a cross fade between these two is what I'm after.